# Text editor for Mac that supports editing files via an SSH session

Tags: osx, text-editor

I would like a text editor with the following parameters:

1. Works on latest version of OSX
2. Supports editing files remotely via SSH, like Atom does [via a plugin](https://atom.io/packages/remote-atom)
3. Doesn't crash all the time (which is why I want to switch over from Atom)

Bonus points for code/Markdown highlight support

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Visual Studio Code for Mac](https://code.visualstudio.com/download) along with the [VS Code Remote SSH plugin](https://code.visualstudio.com/learn/develop-cloud/ssh-lab-machines).

Answer (score 1):

[Komodo Edit](https://github.com/Komodo/KomodoEdit) is cross-platform, and supports editing through SFTP and SCP: https://docs.activestate.com/komodo/11/manual/files.html#opening-remote-files

You can also use [sshfs](https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/wiki/SSHFS) to mount any ssh server as a local filesystem and use any editor you'd like on the files there.